# Using powershell, how do I grant "Log on as service" to an account?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use powershell to configure the account credentials, but I need to grant the account "Log on as a service" right in order for it to work.  How can I do this in powershell?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same, on Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 *Core*, which doesn't ship with ntrights.exe (the tool mentioned in the answer's linked article).  Any further help?

Comment: another option here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Add-log-on-as-a-service-a64dd63c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a link that you could also do within PS: [original](http://www.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/microsoft.public.windowsxp.security_admin/2003-12/2865.html) | [archived](http://web.archive.org/web/20170421105857/http://www.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/microsoft.public.windowsxp.security_admin/2003-12/2865.html).

The problem is that there aren't really any public APIs for managing these settings, so you're a bit stuck using command-line tools provided in ResKits.

Comment: Thank you.  I ended up using ntrights to do this.

ntrights.exe +r SeServiceLogonRight -u <username/groupname>
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=279664

Answer (score 31):

The Powershell script below will grant the ***SeServiceLogonRight*** on the host specified by *computerName* to the user specified by *username* (the script is an excerpt from here: https://gist.github.com/grenade/8519655):

```powershell
<#
.Synopsis
  Grant logon as a service right to the defined user.
.Parameter computerName
  Defines the name of the computer where the user right should be granted.
  Default is the local computer on which the script is run.
.Parameter username
  Defines the username under which the service should run.
  Use the form: domain\username.
  Default is the user under which the script is run.
.Example
  Usage:
  .\GrantSeServiceLogonRight.ps1 -computerName hostname.domain.com -username "domain\username"
#>
param(
  [string] $computerName = ("{0}.{1}" -f $env:COMPUTERNAME.ToLower(), $env:USERDNSDOMAIN.ToLower()),
  [string] $username = ("{0}\{1}" -f $env:USERDOMAIN, $env:USERNAME)
)
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -Script {
  param([string] $username)
  $tempPath = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath()
  $import = Join-Path -Path $tempPath -ChildPath "import.inf"
  if(Test-Path $import) { Remove-Item -Path $import -Force }
  $export = Join-Path -Path $tempPath -ChildPath "export.inf"
  if(Test-Path $export) { Remove-Item -Path $export -Force }
  $secedt = Join-Path -Path $tempPath -ChildPath "secedt.sdb"
  if(Test-Path $secedt) { Remove-Item -Path $secedt -Force }
  try {
    Write-Host ("Granting SeServiceLogonRight to user account: {0} on host: {1}." -f $username, $computerName)
    $sid = ((New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($username)).Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])).Value
    secedit /export /cfg $export
    $sids = (Select-String $export -Pattern "SeServiceLogonRight").Line
    foreach ($line in @("[Unicode]", "Unicode=yes", "[System Access]", "[Event Audit]", "[Registry Values]", "[Version]", "signature=`"`$CHICAGO$`"", "Revision=1", "[Profile Description]", "Description=GrantLogOnAsAService security template", "[Privilege Rights]", "$sids,*$sid")){
      Add-Content $import $line
    }
    secedit /import /db $secedt /cfg $import
    secedit /configure /db $secedt
    gpupdate /force
    Remove-Item -Path $import -Force
    Remove-Item -Path $export -Force
    Remove-Item -Path $secedt -Force
  } catch {
    Write-Host ("Failed to grant SeServiceLogonRight to user account: {0} on host: {1}." -f $username, $computerName)
    $error[0]
  }
} -ArgumentList $username
```

Comment: Is there a bug for `[Privilege Rights]` section? If we have no any accounts with "Logon as a service" permission then we get `,*target-sid` instead of `SeServiceLogonRight = *target-sid`

Answer (score 11):

This function is a nice balance of concise and functional. It checks to see if the user already has the right before attempting to grant it.

I have not tested this for all types of Privilege Rights but it should work for most.

```
function Add-RightToUser([string] $Username, $Right) {
    $tmp = New-TemporaryFile

    $TempConfigFile = "$tmp.inf"
    $TempDbFile = "$tmp.sdb"

    Write-Host "Getting current policy"
    secedit /export /cfg $TempConfigFile

    $sid = ((New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($Username)).Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])).Value

    $currentConfig = Get-Content -Encoding ascii $TempConfigFile

    $newConfig = $null

    if ($currentConfig | Select-String -Pattern "^$Right = ") {
        if ($currentConfig | Select-String -Pattern "^$Right .*$sid.*$") {
            Write-Host "Already has right"
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "Adding $Right to $Username"

            $newConfig = $currentConfig -replace "^$Right .+", "`$0,*$sid"
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Right $Right did not exist in config. Adding $Right to $Username."

        $newConfig = $currentConfig -replace "^\[Privilege Rights\]$", "`$0`n$Right = *$sid"
    }

    if ($newConfig) {
        Set-Content -Path $TempConfigFile -Encoding ascii -Value $newConfig

        Write-Host "Validating configuration"
        $validationResult = secedit /validate $TempConfigFile

        if ($validationResult | Select-String '.*invalid.*') {
            throw $validationResult;
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "Validation Succeeded"
        }

        Write-Host "Importing new policy on temp database"
        secedit /import /cfg $TempConfigFile /db $TempDbFile

        Write-Host "Applying new policy to machine"
        secedit /configure /db $TempDbFile /cfg $TempConfigFile

        Write-Host "Updating policy"
        gpupdate /force

        Remove-Item $tmp* -ea 0
    }
}

#Example
Add-RightToUser -Username 'MyDomain\MyUser' -Right 'SeServiceLogonRight'
```

Removal

```
function Remove-RightFromUser([string] $Username, $Right) {
    $tmp = New-TemporaryFile

    $TempConfigFile = "$tmp.inf"
    $TempDbFile = "$tmp.sdb"

    Write-Host "Getting current policy"
    secedit /export /cfg $TempConfigFile

    $sid = ((New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($Username)).Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])).Value

    $currentConfig = Get-Content -Encoding ascii $TempConfigFile

    if ($currentConfig | Select-String -Pattern "^$Right .*$sid.*$") {
        Write-Host "Removing $Right from $Username"

        $newConfig = $currentConfig -replace "^($Right = .*?)(?>,\*$sid(.*?$)|\*$sid,(.*?$)|\*$sid$)", '$1$2$3'

        Set-Content -Path $TempConfigFile -Encoding ascii -Value $newConfig

        Write-Host "Validating configuration"
        $validationResult = secedit /validate $TempConfigFile

        if ($validationResult | Select-String '.*invalid.*') {
            throw $validationResult;
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "Validation Succeeded"
        }

        Write-Host "Importing new policy on temp database"
        secedit /import /cfg $TempConfigFile /db $TempDbFile

        Write-Host "Applying new policy to machine"
        secedit /configure /db $TempDbFile /cfg $TempConfigFile

        Write-Host "Updating policy"
        gpupdate /force

        Remove-Item $tmp* -ea 0
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "User $Username did not have right"
    }
}

#Example
Remove-RightFromUser -Username 'MyDomain\MyUser' -Right 'SeServiceLogonRight'
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you. Now I'd just like to see how to remove the SeServiceLogon privilege.

Comment: @JamesTSnell I have added a removal example as you have requested.

Comment: You need single quotes around your regex replace parameter (`'$1$2$3'` instead of `"$1$2$3"`) for the `Remove-RightFromUser` so that it uses capture group values, instead of letting PWSH try to interpolate those (nonexistant) vars.

Comment: @neumann1990 thank you. I have applied that edit to the example.

Comment: Sometimes the setting does not only contain a SID, but also a user name. In these cases the removal would not work this way, because it only checks the SID.

Comment: @NiklasPeter do you have an example of a right that behaves that way? I haven't come across any like that yet. I'd be happy to improve this answer if there's a test scenario I can use.

Comment: @KeithBanner I do not think, that it is specific to a right, but possible for all rights:
````SeBatchLogonRight = PBackup,PBackupReader```` is from my export.

Comment: Suggestion: 
````if (($currentConfig | Select-String -Pattern "^$Right .*$sid.*$") -or ($currentConfig | Select-String -Pattern "^$Right .*\b$Username\b.*$")) {
            Write-Host "Removing $Right from $Username"

            $newConfig = $currentConfig -replace "^($Right = .*?)(?>,\*$sid(.*?$)|\*$sid,(.*?$)|\*$sid$)", '$1$2$3'
            $newConfig = $newConfig -replace "^($Right = .*?)(?>,$Username\b(.*?$)|$Username,(.*?$)|$Username$)", '$1$2$3'````

Answer (score 10):

This is how I solved it:

Based on: [this article](http://www.morgantechspace.com/2013/11/Set-or-Grant-Logon-As-A-Service-right-to-User.html)

You can download [Carbon from here](http://get-carbon.org/)

First import Carbon module as follows:

```
Import-Module -Name $Path_To_Carbon -Global -Prefix CA

[array]$UserPrivileges = Get-CAPrivileges -Identity $UserName;
[bool]$LogOnAsAServiceprivilegeFound = $false;

if ($UserPrivileges.Length > 0)
{
    if ($UserPrivileges -contains "SeServiceLogonRight")
    {
        $LogOnAsAServiceprivilegeFound = $true;
    }
}

if ($LogOnAsAServiceprivilegeFound -eq $false)
{
    Grant-CAPrivilege -Identity $UserName "SeServiceLogonRight"
}
```

Comment: No need to check existing privileges. It works even if you call it multiple times: Grant-CAPrivilege -Identity $UserName "SeServiceLogonRight"

Comment: Thank you so much for the Carbon idea.  The article is using outdated calls, I posted what worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313831/using-powershell-how-do-i-grant-log-on-as-service-to-an-account/67010294#67010294

Comment: Used this solution as well with success, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

This is not pure PowerShell but at least you do not need a third party tool.
Everything is already on your computer and works from the command line.

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator

#The SID you want to add
$AccountSid = 'S-1-5-21-1234567890-1234567890-123456789-500'

$ExportFile = 'c:\temp\CurrentConfig.inf'
$SecDb = 'c:\temp\secedt.sdb'
$ImportFile = 'c:\temp\NewConfig.inf'

#Export the current configuration
secedit /export /cfg $ExportFile

#Find the current list of SIDs having already this right
$CurrentServiceLogonRight = Get-Content -Path $ExportFile |
    Where-Object -FilterScript {$PSItem -match 'SeServiceLogonRight'}

#Create a new configuration file and add the new SID
$FileContent = @'
[Unicode]
Unicode=yes
[System Access]
[Event Audit]
[Registry Values]
[Version]
signature="$CHICAGO$"
Revision=1
[Profile Description]
Description=GrantLogOnAsAService security template
[Privilege Rights]
{0}*{1}
'@ -f $(
        if($CurrentServiceLogonRight){"$CurrentServiceLogonRight,"}
        else{'SeServiceLogonRight = '}
    ), $AccountSid

Set-Content -Path $ImportFile -Value $FileContent

#Import the new configuration 
secedit /import /db $SecDb /cfg $ImportFile
secedit /configure /db $SecDb
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a Windows API that provides access to the Local Security Policy: `AdvAPI32.dll` and the `Lsa*` methods.

You can take advantage of PowerShell's ability to add .NET types to the current session, and .NET's P/Invoke to call Windows APIs, in order to grant a user the 'Log on as a service' permission from PowerShell.

As a minimal example*, you first need to add some new .NET types to the current PowerShell session to work with the Windows API:

```
Add-Type @'
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public enum LSA_AccessPolicy : long
{
    // Other values omitted for clarity
    POLICY_ALL_ACCESS = 0x00001FFFL
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct LSA_UNICODE_STRING
{
    public UInt16 Length;
    public UInt16 MaximumLength;
    public IntPtr Buffer;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES
{
    public UInt32 Length;
    public IntPtr RootDirectory;
    public LSA_UNICODE_STRING ObjectName;
    public UInt32 Attributes;
    public IntPtr SecurityDescriptor;
    public IntPtr SecurityQualityOfService;
}

public static partial class AdvAPI32 {
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, PreserveSig = true)]
    public static extern uint LsaOpenPolicy(
        ref LSA_UNICODE_STRING SystemName,
        ref LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes,
        uint DesiredAccess,
        out IntPtr PolicyHandle);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern Int32 LsaClose(IntPtr ObjectHandle);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, PreserveSig = true)]
    public static extern uint LsaAddAccountRights(
        IntPtr PolicyHandle,
        byte[] AccountSid,
        LSA_UNICODE_STRING[] UserRights,
        uint CountOfRights);
}
'@
```

Then, you need to open a handle to the local security policy:

```
function Get-LsaPolicyHandle() {
    $system = New-Object LSA_UNICODE_STRING
    $attrib = New-Object LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES -Property @{
        Length = 0
        RootDirectory = [System.IntPtr]::Zero
        Attributes = 0
        SecurityDescriptor = [System.IntPtr]::Zero
        SecurityQualityOfService = [System.IntPtr]::Zero
    };

    $handle = [System.IntPtr]::Zero

    $hr = [AdvAPI32]::LsaOpenPolicy([ref] $system, [ref]$attrib, [LSA_AccessPolicy]::POLICY_ALL_ACCESS, [ref]$handle)

    if (($hr -ne 0) -or ($handle -eq [System.IntPtr]::Zero)) {
        Write-Error "Failed to open Local Security Authority policy. Error code: $hr"
    } else {
        $handle
    }
}
```

To add a new right, you first need to create a new one:

```
function New-Right([string]$rightName){
    $unicodeCharSize = 2
    New-Object LSA_UNICODE_STRING -Property @{
        Buffer = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::StringToHGlobalUni($rightName)
        Length = $rightName.Length * $unicodeCharSize
        MaximumLength = ($rightName.Length + 1) * $unicodeCharSize
    }
}
```

And then you can add that right to the security policy:

```
function Grant-Rights([System.IntPtr]$policyHandle, [byte[]]$sid, [LSA_UNICODE_STRING[]]$rights) {
    $result = [AdvAPI32]::LsaAddAccountRights($policyHandle, $sid, $rights, 1)
    if ($result -ne 0) {
        Write-Error "Failed to grant right. Error code $result"
    } 
}
```

So putting it all together, you can then consume those functions:

```
function Grant-LogonAsServiceRight([byte[]]$sid) { 
    $logonAsServiceRightName = "SeServiceLogonRight"

    try {
        $policy = Get-LsaPolicyHandle
        $right = New-Right $logonAsServiceRightName
        Grant-Rights $policy $sid @($right)
    }
    finally {
        if($null -ne $policy){
            [AdvAPI32]::LsaClose($policy) | Out-Null
        }
    }
}
```

There are other methods in `AdvAPI32` to enumerate a user's account rights, remove a right etc.

--

*I followed the code in the [Azure DevOps Pipeline Agent repo](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/master/src/Agent.Listener/Configuration.Windows/NativeWindowsServiceHelper.cs) to figure out how to work with the Local Security Policy methods in `AdvAPI32`.

Answer (score 5):

Use Carbon!  Some of the above suggestions are outdated, here is what worked for me:

(In powershell with elevated privs)

```
Install-Module -Name 'Carbon' -AllowClobber
Import-Module 'Carbon'
$Identity = "<username>"
$privilege = "SeServiceLogonRight"
$CarbonDllPath = "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Carbon\2.10.2\bin\fullclr\Carbon.dll"
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($CarbonDllPath)
[Carbon.Security.Privilege]::GrantPrivileges($Identity, $privilege)
```

Comment: Depending on your PowerShell version the module might install elsewhere, instead I'm using `$CarbonDllPath = "$((Get-Module -name 'Carbon').Path | Split-Path)\bin\fullclr\Carbon.dll"` to set the DllPath dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

Solution without importing the whole db

```
function setSecurityPolicy {
Param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
    [string] $username,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
    [string] $securityField
)
$sid;
if($username -like "*\*"){
    $user = $username.split('\')
    $domain=$user[0]
    $usernametemp=$user[1]
    $sid=(get-wmiobject Win32_useraccount -filter "name='$usernametemp' and Domain='$domain'").SID
} else {
    $sid=(get-wmiobject Win32_useraccount -filter "name='$username' and Domain='$($env:COMPUTERNAME)'").SID
}
if(-not($sid)){
    try{
        $sid= (Get-Localgroup "$username").SID.VALUE
    } catch{
    
    }
}

if(-not($sid)) {
    $Host.UI.WriteErrorLine("setSecurityPolicy error : Account $username not found!")
    exit 1
}
$tmp = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
secedit.exe /export /cfg "$tmp" | Out-Null

$currentSetting = Select-String -Pattern "$securityField = (.*)" -path $tmp | select -Expand Matches |  % { $_.Groups[1].Value }
remove-item $tmp -Force

if($currentSetting -notlike  "*$sid*" ){
    Write-Host "Modify Setting ""$securityField"""
    if( [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($currentSetting) ) {
        $currentSetting = "*$sid"
    } else {
        $currentSetting = "*$sid,$currentSetting"
    }
    $outfile = @"
[Unicode]
Unicode=yes
[Version]
signature="`$CHICAGO`$"
Revision=1
[Privilege Rights]
$securityField = $currentSetting
"@
    $tmp2 = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
    Write-Host "Import new settings to Local Security Policy"
    $outfile | Set-Content -Path $tmp2 -Encoding Unicode -Force

    try {
        secedit.exe /configure /db "secedit.sdb" /cfg "$tmp2" /areas USER_RIGHTS 
    } finally { 
        remove-item $tmp2 -Force
    }
}
}
#example usage
setSecurityPolicy -username 'IIS_IUSRS' -securityField 'SeServiceLogonRight'
setSecurityPolicy -username 'IIS_IUSRS' -securityField 'SeBatchLogonRight'
setSecurityPolicy -username 'IIS_IUSRS' -securityField 'SeImpersonatePrivilege'
```

Comment: Provide a usage example

Comment: Usage example added. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell doesn't have any native means of doing this, which means you'd probably be looking at either WMI or ADSI - you're more likely to find examples in VBScript, which has been around longer, although personally I don't think I've ever figured out how to programmatically assign user rights. Doesn't mean it can't be done, though, but you'll probably be looking outside the realm of PowerShell specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Brendan Lane answer.

To get the "Sid" for the user use this function:

```
function Get-SidForUser {
    param ([string]$UserName)
    $sid = ((New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($UserName)).Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]))
    [byte[]]$bytes = New-Object byte[] $sid.BinaryLength;
    $sid.GetBinaryForm($bytes, 0);
    return $bytes
}
```

Putting it all together:

```
Grant-LogonAsServiceRight (Get-SidForUser -UserName $ServiceAccount)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following script to Remotely and Locally modify the Security Policy, with my script you can run against multiple machines, users, and user rights:
[Link to my Get / Set User Rights Blog Post](https://blakedrumm.com/blog/set-and-check-user-rights-assignment/).

You can copy and paste the script to the Powershell ISE, just **edit line 437** *(near bottom of script)* to include the required parameters `-UserRight` and `-Add` *or* `-Remove`. The other parameters are optional `-ComputerName`, `-UserName`:

```
<#
    .Synopsis
        Add and Remove User Right(s) for defined user(s) and computer(s).
    
    .DESCRIPTION
        Add and Remove User Rights via Powershell.
    
    .PARAMETER AddRight
        You want to Add a user right.
    
    .Parameter ComputerName
        Defines the name of the computer where the user right should be granted. This can be multiple values, comma seperated.
        Default is the local computer on which the script is run.
    
    .PARAMETER RemoveRight
        You want to Remove a user right.
    
    .Parameter Username
        Defines the Username under which the service should run. This can be multiple values, comma seperated.
        Use the form: domain\Username.
        Default is the user under which the script is run.
    
    .PARAMETER UserRight
        Defines the User Right you want to set. This can be multiple values, comma seperated.
        Name of the right you want to add to: SeServiceLogonRight
        There is no default for this argument
        
        All of the Options you can use:
            Replace a process level token (SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege)
            Generate security audits (SeAuditPrivilege)
            Back up files and directories (SeBackupPrivilege)
            Log on as a batch job (SeBatchLogonRight)
            Bypass traverse checking (SeChangeNotifyPrivilege)
            Create global objects (SeCreateGlobalPrivilege)
            Create a pagefile (SeCreatePagefilePrivilege)
            Create permanent shared objects (SeCreatePermanentPrivilege)
            Create symbolic links (SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege)
            Create a token object (SeCreateTokenPrivilege)
            Debug programs (SeDebugPrivilege)
            Obtain an impersonation token for another user in the same session (SeDelegateSessionUserImpersonatePrivilege)
            Deny log on as a batch job (SeDenyBatchLogonRight)
            Deny log on locally (SeDenyInteractiveLogonRight)
            Deny access to this computer from the network (SeDenyNetworkLogonRight)
            Deny log on through Remote Desktop Services (SeDenyRemoteInteractiveLogonRight)
            Deny log on as a service (SeDenyServiceLogonRight)
            Enable computer and user accounts to be trusted for delegation (SeEnableDelegationPrivilege)
            Impersonate a client after authentication (SeImpersonatePrivilege)
            Increase scheduling priority (SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege)
            Adjust memory quotas for a process (SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege)
            Increase a process working set (SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege)
            Allow log on locally (SeInteractiveLogonRight)
            Load and unload device drivers (SeLoadDriverPrivilege)
            Lock pages in memory (SeLockMemoryPrivilege)
            Add workstations to domain (SeMachineAccountPrivilege)
            Perform volume maintenance tasks (SeManageVolumePrivilege)
            Access this computer from the network (SeNetworkLogonRight)
            Profile single process (SeProfileSingleProcessPrivilege)
            Modify an object label (SeRelabelPrivilege)
            Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services (SeRemoteInteractiveLogonRight)
            Force shutdown from a remote system (SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege)
            Restore files and directories (SeRestorePrivilege)
            Manage auditing and security log (SeSecurityPrivilege)
            Log on as a service (SeServiceLogonRight)
            Shut down the system (SeShutdownPrivilege)
            Synchronize directory service data (SeSyncAgentPrivilege)
            Modify firmware environment values (SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege)
            Profile system performance (SeSystemProfilePrivilege)
            Change the system time (SeSystemtimePrivilege)
            Take ownership of files or other objects (SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege)
            Act as part of the operating system (SeTcbPrivilege)
            Change the time zone (SeTimeZonePrivilege)
            Access Credential Manager as a trusted caller (SeTrustedCredManAccessPrivilege)
            Remove computer from docking station (SeUndockPrivilege)
    
    .Example
        Usage:
        Single Users
            Add User Right "Log on as a service" for CONTOSO\User:
            .\Set-UserRights.ps1 -AddRight -Username CONTOSO\User -UserRight SeServiceLogonRight
            
            Add User Right "Log on as a batch job" for CONTOSO\User:
            .\Set-UserRights.ps1 -AddRight -Username CONTOSO\User -UserRight SeBatchLogonRight

            Remove User Right "Log on as a batch job" for CONTOSO\User:
            .\Set-UserRights.ps1 -RemoveRight -Username CONTOSO\User -UserRight SeBatchLogonRight
            
            Add User Right "Allow log on locally" for current user:
            .\Set-UserRights.ps1 -AddRight -UserRight SeInteractiveLogonRight

            Remove User Right "Allow log on locally" for current user:
            .\Set-UserRights.ps1 -RemoveRight -UserRight SeInteractiveLogonRight
        
        Multiple Users / Services / Computers
            Add User Right "Log on as a service" and "Log on as a batch job" for CONTOSO\User and run on, local machine and SQL.contoso.com:
            .\Set-UserRights.ps1 -AddRight -UserRight SeServiceLogonRight, SeBatchLogonRight -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME, SQL.contoso.com -UserName CONTOSO\User1, CONTOSO\User2
    
    .Notes
        Original Creator: Bill Loytty (weloytty)
        Based on this script found here: https://github.com/weloytty/QuirkyPSFunctions/blob/main/Source/Users/Grant-LogOnAsService.ps1
        I modified to my own needs: https://github.com/blakedrumm/SCOM-Scripts-and-SQL/blob/master/Powershell/General%20Functions/Set-UserRights.ps1
        
        My blog post: https://blakedrumm.com/blog/set-and-check-user-rights-assignment/
        
        Author: Blake Drumm (blakedrumm@microsoft.com)
        First Created on: January 5th, 2022
        Last Modified on: October 12th, 2022
#>
param
(
    [Parameter(Position = 0,
               HelpMessage = 'You want to Add a user right.')]
    [Alias('add')]
    [switch]$AddRight,
    [Parameter(Position = 1)]
    [Alias('computer')]
    [array]$ComputerName,
    [Parameter(Position = 2,
               HelpMessage = 'You want to Remove a user right.')]
    [switch]$RemoveRight,
    [Parameter(Position = 3)]
    [Alias('user')]
    [array]$Username,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false,
               Position = 4)]
    [ValidateSet('SeNetworkLogonRight', 'SeBackupPrivilege', 'SeChangeNotifyPrivilege', 'SeSystemtimePrivilege', 'SeCreatePagefilePrivilege', 'SeDebugPrivilege', 'SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege', 'SeAuditPrivilege', 'SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege', 'SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege', 'SeLoadDriverPrivilege', 'SeBatchLogonRight', 'SeServiceLogonRight', 'SeInteractiveLogonRight', 'SeSecurityPrivilege', 'SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege', 'SeProfileSingleProcessPrivilege', 'SeSystemProfilePrivilege', 'SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege', 'SeRestorePrivilege', 'SeShutdownPrivilege', 'SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege', 'SeDenyNetworkLogonRight', 'SeDenyInteractiveLogonRight', 'SeUndockPrivilege', 'SeManageVolumePrivilege', 'SeRemoteInteractiveLogonRight', 'SeImpersonatePrivilege', 'SeCreateGlobalPrivilege', 'SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege', 'SeTimeZonePrivilege', 'SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege', 'SeDelegateSessionUserImpersonatePrivilege', 'SeMachineAccountPrivilege', 'SeTrustedCredManAccessPrivilege', 'SeTcbPrivilege', 'SeCreateTokenPrivilege', 'SeCreatePermanentPrivilege', 'SeDenyBatchLogonRight', 'SeDenyServiceLogonRight', 'SeDenyRemoteInteractiveLogonRight', 'SeEnableDelegationPrivilege', 'SeLockMemoryPrivilege', 'SeRelabelPrivilege', 'SeSyncAgentPrivilege', IgnoreCase = $true)]
    [Alias('right')]
    [array]$UserRight
)
BEGIN
{
    
    Write-Output '==================================================================='
    Write-Output '==========================  Start of Script ======================='
    Write-Output '==================================================================='
    
    $checkingpermission = "Checking for elevated permissions..."
    $scriptout += $checkingpermission
    Write-Output $checkingpermission
    if (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))
    {
        $currentPath = $myinvocation.mycommand.definition
        $nopermission = "Insufficient permissions to run this script. Attempting to open the PowerShell script ($currentPath) as administrator."
        $scriptout += $nopermission
        Write-Warning $nopermission
        # We are not running "as Administrator" - so relaunch as administrator
        # ($MyInvocation.Line -split '\.ps1[\s\''\"]\s*', 2)[-1]
        Start-Process powershell.exe "-File", ('"{0}"' -f $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) -Verb RunAs
        break
    }
    else
    {
        $permissiongranted = " Currently running as administrator - proceeding with script execution..."
        Write-Output $permissiongranted
    }
    
    Function Time-Stamp
    {
        $TimeStamp = Get-Date -UFormat "%B %d, %Y @ %r"
        return "$TimeStamp - "
    }
}
PROCESS
{
    function Inner-SetUserRights
    {
        param
        (
            [Parameter(Position = 0,
                       HelpMessage = 'You want to Add a user right.')]
            [Alias('add')]
            [switch]$AddRight,
            [Parameter(Position = 1)]
            [Alias('computer')]
            [array]$ComputerName,
            [Parameter(Position = 2,
                       HelpMessage = 'You want to Remove a user right.')]
            [switch]$RemoveRight,
            [Parameter(Position = 3)]
            [Alias('user')]
            [array]$Username,
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $false,
                       Position = 4)]
            [Alias('right')]
            [array]$UserRight
        )
        if (!$UserRight)
        {
            Write-Warning "Inner Function: Unable to continue because you did not supply the '-UserRight' parameter."
            break
        }
        if (!$AddRight -and !$RemoveRight)
        {
            Write-Warning "Inner Function: Unable to continue because you did not supply the '-AddRight' or '-RemoveRight' switches."
            break
        }
        elseif ($AddRight -and $RemoveRight)
        {
            Write-Warning "Inner Function: Unable to continue because you used both the '-AddRight' and '-RemoveRight' switches. Run again with just one of these present, either Add or Remove."
            break
        }
        elseif ($AddRight)
        {
            Write-Verbose "Inner Function: Detected -AddRight switch in execution."
            $ActionType = 'Adding'
        }
        elseif ($RemoveRight)
        {
            Write-Verbose "Inner Function: Detected -RemoveRight switch in execution."
            $ActionType = 'Removing'
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Warning "Something is wrong, detected logic is broken before executing main function. Exiting."
            break
        }
        Function Time-Stamp
        {
            $TimeStamp = Get-Date -UFormat "%B %d, %Y @ %r"
            return "$TimeStamp - "
        }
        $tempPath = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath()
        $import = Join-Path -Path $tempPath -ChildPath "import.inf"
        if (Test-Path $import) { Remove-Item -Path $import -Force }
        $export = Join-Path -Path $tempPath -ChildPath "export.inf"
        if (Test-Path $export) { Remove-Item -Path $export -Force }
        $secedt = Join-Path -Path $tempPath -ChildPath "secedt.sdb"
        if (Test-Path $secedt) { Remove-Item -Path $secedt -Force }
        $Error.Clear()
        try
        {
            foreach ($right in $UserRight)
            {
                $UserLogonRight = switch ($right)
                {
                    "SeBatchLogonRight"                 { "Log on as a batch job (SeBatchLogonRight)" }
                    "SeDenyBatchLogonRight"             { "Deny log on as a batch job (SeDenyBatchLogonRight)" }
                    "SeDenyInteractiveLogonRight"       { "Deny log on locally (SeDenyInteractiveLogonRight)" }
                    "SeDenyNetworkLogonRight"           { "Deny access to this computer from the network (SeDenyNetworkLogonRight)" }
                    "SeDenyRemoteInteractiveLogonRight" { "Deny log on through Remote Desktop Services (SeDenyRemoteInteractiveLogonRight)" }
                    "SeDenyServiceLogonRight"           { "Deny log on as a service (SeDenyServiceLogonRight)" }
                    "SeInteractiveLogonRight"           { "Allow log on locally (SeInteractiveLogonRight)" }
                    "SeNetworkLogonRight"               { "Access this computer from the network (SeNetworkLogonRight)" }
                    "SeRemoteInteractiveLogonRight"     { "Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services (SeRemoteInteractiveLogonRight)" }
                    "SeServiceLogonRight"               { "Log on as a service (SeServiceLogonRight)" }
                    Default                             { "($right)" }
                }
                Write-Output ("$(Time-Stamp)$ActionType `"$UserLogonRight`" right for user account: '$Username' on host: '$env:COMPUTERNAME'")
                if ($Username -match "^S-.*-.*-.*$|^S-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*$|^S-.*-.*-.*-.*-.*$|^S-.*-.*-.*-.*$")
                {
                    $sid = $Username
                }
                else
                {
                    $sid = ((New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($Username)).Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])).Value
                }
                secedit /export /cfg $export | Out-Null
                #Change the below to any right you would like
                $sids = (Select-String $export -Pattern "$right").Line
                if ($ActionType -eq 'Adding')
                {
                    # If right has no value it needs to be added
                    if ($sids -eq $null)
                    {
                        $sids = "$right = *$sid"
                        $sidList = $sids
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $sidList = "$sids,*$sid"
                    }
                }
                elseif ($ActionType -eq 'Removing')
                {
                    $sidList = "$($sids.Replace("*$sid", '').Replace("$Username", '').Replace(",,", ',').Replace("= ,", '= '))"
                }
                Write-Verbose $sidlist
                foreach ($line in @("[Unicode]", "Unicode=yes", "[System Access]", "[Event Audit]", "[Registry Values]", "[Version]", "signature=`"`$CHICAGO$`"", "Revision=1", "[Profile Description]", "Description=$ActionType `"$UserLogonRight`" right for user account: $Username", "[Privilege Rights]", "$sidList"))
                {
                    Add-Content $import $line
                }
            }
            
            secedit /import /db $secedt /cfg $import | Out-Null
            secedit /configure /db $secedt | Out-Null
            gpupdate /force | Out-Null
            Write-Verbose "The script will not delete the following paths due to running in verbose mode, please remove these files manually if needed:"
            Write-Verbose "`$import : $import"
            Write-Verbose "`$export : $export"
            Write-Verbose "`$secedt : $secedt"
            
            if ($VerbosePreference.value__ -eq 0)
            {
                Remove-Item -Path $import -Force | Out-Null
                Remove-Item -Path $export -Force | Out-Null
                Remove-Item -Path $secedt -Force | Out-Null
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Output ("$(Time-Stamp)Failure occurred while granting `"$right`" to user account: '$Username' on host: '$env:COMPUTERNAME'")
            Write-Output "Error Details: $error"
        }
    }
    $InnerSetUserRightFunctionScript = "function Inner-SetUserRights { ${function:Inner-SetUserRights} }"
    function Set-UserRights
    {
        param
        (
            [Parameter(Position = 0,
                       HelpMessage = 'You want to Add a user right.')]
            [Alias('add')]
            [switch]$AddRight,
            [Parameter(Position = 1)]
            [Alias('computer')]
            [array]$ComputerName,
            [Parameter(Position = 2,
                       HelpMessage = 'You want to Remove a user right.')]
            [switch]$RemoveRight,
            [Parameter(Position = 3)]
            [Alias('user')]
            [array]$Username,
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $false,
                       Position = 4)]
            [ValidateSet('SeNetworkLogonRight', 'SeBackupPrivilege', 'SeChangeNotifyPrivilege', 'SeSystemtimePrivilege', 'SeCreatePagefilePrivilege', 'SeDebugPrivilege', 'SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege', 'SeAuditPrivilege', 'SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege', 'SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege', 'SeLoadDriverPrivilege', 'SeBatchLogonRight', 'SeServiceLogonRight', 'SeInteractiveLogonRight', 'SeSecurityPrivilege', 'SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege', 'SeProfileSingleProcessPrivilege', 'SeSystemProfilePrivilege', 'SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege', 'SeRestorePrivilege', 'SeShutdownPrivilege', 'SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege', 'SeDenyNetworkLogonRight', 'SeDenyInteractiveLogonRight', 'SeUndockPrivilege', 'SeManageVolumePrivilege', 'SeRemoteInteractiveLogonRight', 'SeImpersonatePrivilege', 'SeCreateGlobalPrivilege', 'SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege', 'SeTimeZonePrivilege', 'SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege', 'SeDelegateSessionUserImpersonatePrivilege', 'SeMachineAccountPrivilege', 'SeTrustedCredManAccessPrivilege', 'SeTcbPrivilege', 'SeCreateTokenPrivilege', 'SeCreatePermanentPrivilege', 'SeDenyBatchLogonRight', 'SeDenyServiceLogonRight', 'SeDenyRemoteInteractiveLogonRight', 'SeEnableDelegationPrivilege', 'SeLockMemoryPrivilege', 'SeRelabelPrivilege', 'SeSyncAgentPrivilege', IgnoreCase = $true)]
            [Alias('right')]
            [array]$UserRight
        )
        if (!$Username)
        {
            $Username = "$env:USERDOMAIN`\$env:USERNAME"
        }
        if (!$UserRight)
        {
            Write-Warning "Main Function: Unable to continue because you did not supply the '-UserRight' parameter."
            break
        }
        if (!$AddRight -and !$RemoveRight)
        {
            Write-Warning "Main Function: Unable to continue because you did not supply the '-AddRight' or '-RemoveRight' switches."
            break
        }
        elseif ($AddRight -and $RemoveRight)
        {
            Write-Warning "Main Function: Unable to continue because you used both the '-AddRight' and '-RemoveRight' switches. Run again with just one of these present, either Add or Remove."
            break
        }
        elseif ($AddRight)
        {
            Write-Verbose "Main Function: Detected -AddRight switch in execution."
            $ActionType = 'Adding'
        }
        elseif ($RemoveRight)
        {
            Write-Verbose "Main Function: Detected -RemoveRight switch in execution."
            $ActionType = 'Removing'
        }
        if (!$ComputerName)
        {
            $ComputerName = $env:ComputerName
        }
        foreach ($user in $Username)
        {
            foreach ($right in $UserRight)
            {
                foreach ($computer in $ComputerName)
                {
                    if ($computer -match $env:COMPUTERNAME)
                    {
                        Inner-SetUserRights -UserRight $right -Username $user -AddRight:$AddRight -RemoveRight:$RemoveRight
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -Script {
                            param ($script,
                                [string]$Username,
                                [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
                                [array]$UserRight,
                                $AddRight,
                                $RemoveRight,
                                $VerbosePreference)
                            . ([ScriptBlock]::Create($script))
                            $VerbosePreference = $VerbosePreference
                            $Error.Clear()
                            try
                            {
                                if ($VerbosePreference -eq 0)
                                {
                                    Inner-SetUserRights -Username $Username -UserRight $UserRight -AddRight:$AddRight -RemoveRight:$RemoveRight
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Inner-SetUserRights -Username $Username -UserRight $UserRight -AddRight:$AddRight -RemoveRight:$RemoveRight -Verbose
                                }
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                $info = [PSCustomObject]@{
                                    Exception = $Error.Exception.Message
                                    Reason    = $Error.CategoryInfo.Reason
                                    Target    = $Error.CategoryInfo.TargetName
                                    Script    = $Error.InvocationInfo.ScriptName
                                    Line      = $Error.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber
                                    Column    = $Error.InvocationInfo.OffsetInLine
                                    Date      = Get-Date
                                    User      = $env:username
                                }
                                Write-Warning "$info"
                            }
                            
                        } -ArgumentList $InnerSetUserRightFunctionScript, $user, $right, $AddRight, $RemoveRight, $VerbosePreference
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    if ($ComputerName -or $Username -or $UserRight -or $RemoveRight)
    {
        foreach ($user in $Username)
        {
            Set-UserRights -ComputerName $ComputerName -Username $user -UserRight $UserRight -AddRight:$AddRight -RemoveRight:$RemoveRight
        }
    }
    else
    {
        
     <# Edit line 437 to modify the default command run when this script is executed.
       Example: 
            Set-UserRights -AddRight -UserRight SeServiceLogonRight, SeBatchLogonRight -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME, SQL.contoso.com -UserName CONTOSO\User1, CONTOSO\User2
            or
            Set-UserRights -AddRight -UserRight SeBatchLogonRight -Username S-1-5-11
            or
            Set-UserRights -RemoveRight -UserRight SeBatchLogonRight -Username CONTOSO\User2
            or
            Set-UserRights -RemoveRight -UserRight SeServiceLogonRight, SeBatchLogonRight -Username CONTOSO\User1
       #>
        Set-UserRights
    }
}
END
{
    Write-Output "$(Time-Stamp)Script Completed!"
}
```

Answer (score -3):

There was a PowerShell script available at TechNet Gallery that handled this.
It can still be downloaded through WayBack Machine.

Then you can run

```
.".\Add Account To LogonAsService.ps1" "DOMAIN\Account"
```

http://web.archive.org/web/20161222202741/https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Grant-Log-on-as-a-service-11a50893

Comment: This link is dead.

Comment: The solution provided isn't easy, but the script is still available through Wayback Machine (http://web.archive.org/web/20161222202741/https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Grant-Log-on-as-a-service-11a50893/file/106425/1/Add%20Account%20To%20LogonAsService.zip)