# Granting "LogonAsAService"-rights does not respond

Tags: powershell, windows-server, windows-server-2016

I have a PowerShell-Script that is supposed to install an application.

The application relies on a windows-service, which needs the "LogonAsAService"-right.

I use this code to set the rights:

Powershell:

```
function getUserName {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [System.Net.NetworkCredential]
        $credentials
    )

    if($credentials.Domain){
        return $credentials.Domain + "\" + $credentials.UserName;
    }
    return $env:COMPUTERNAME + "\" + $credentials.UserName;
}

$serviceUserAccountName = getUsername($serverServiceAccount)

function Add-ServiceLogonRight([string] $Username) {
    Write-Host "Enable ServiceLogonRight for $Username"

    $tmp = New-TemporaryFile
    secedit /export /cfg "$tmp.inf" | Out-Null
    (gc -Encoding ascii "$tmp.inf") -replace '^SeServiceLogonRight .+', "`$0,$Username" | sc -Encoding ascii "$tmp.inf"
    secedit /import /cfg "$tmp.inf" /db "$tmp.sdb" | Out-Null
    secedit /configure /db "$tmp.sdb" /cfg "$tmp.inf" | Out-Null
    rm $tmp* -ea 0
}

# Grant rights to the account
Write-Host "Granting logon-as-service user-rights"

Add-ServiceLogonRight $serviceUserAccountName
```

I also tried different approaches, like using this module: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Grant-Revoke-Query-user-26e259b0

**Problem:**

These approaches work in theory, I achieved positive results with both of them, but only for one, or maybe two tries. On many occasions the system (currently a Windows Server 2016) gets to this line (for the code example above, behaviour is similar with the module, but the output looks a bit different, problem seems to be exactly the same):

```
Write-Host "Enable ServiceLogonRight for $Username"
```

The PowerShell does not respond anymore afterwards. All I can do is exiting the entire PowerShell.

The problem seems to be reproducable like this:

- Start the system
- Run the script
- Works.
- Run the script again
- Does not work anymore

=> It seems like it's only working on a freshly started system. This is not possible to ensure for the environment.

Is there a mistake I am making? Is this a known problem? I am really confused by this behaviour and seem unable to find more information on what exactly is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using SeServiceLogonRight as suggested here:

[Using powershell, how do I grant "Log on as service" to an account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313831/using-powershell-how-do-i-grant-log-on-as-service-to-an-account)