# In Powershell script, what is the significance of [signature="$CHICAGO$"]

Tags: powershell

In the solution for "[Using powershell, how do I grant "Log on as service" to an account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313831/using-powershell-how-do-i-grant-log-on-as-service-to-an-account)", what is the significance of - **signature="$CHICAGO$"**

Comment: the backticks before each `$` in the source mean to NOT treat the `$` as part of a variable name. so the purpose is to allow EXACTLY that string to be stored into that here-string.

Comment: "Chicago" was the codename for Windows 95 - `signature=$CHICAGO$` in a policy template simply means "We're using the GPT format introduced in Windows 95".